# How to initiate hping3 with sack (selective ack) option in TCP options

Tags: linux, tcp, ping

I have a scenario on Linux machine, where I wanted to see if `tcp-mss` set with lowest value possible (say 48 bytes) along with the sack (selective ack option) of TCP header.

On my Ubuntu client, `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_sack` returns 1. I was trying to use hping3 utility - `hping3 20.1.1.2 --sign snaidu -d 50 --file test -p 22 --tcp-mss 48`. On the target machine, when I capture the packets using `tcpdump`, I don't see the sack option in TCP header is set.

Appreciate if anyone has come across similar situation and if there is any way forward on this.